Reflection didn't see field
I have melonloader on il2cpp game and try to write mod for it.
I need to get field Joint.massScale from il2cppSystem.Object as ConfigurableJoint : Joint object.
That field exist in UnityExplorer:

And can user directly:

What fails:
.GetMember and .GetMembers: they just don't include that field/property
MemberInfo member = anyObject.GetIl2CppType()
    .GetMember(requested, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static)
    .First();

Recursive GetMember:
static IEnumerable<MemberInfo> GetAllMembersRecursivly(Il2CppSystem.Type type) =>
    type.GetMembers(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static)
    .Concat(type.BaseType == Il2CppType.Of<Il2CppSystem.Object>() ? new MemberInfo[0] : GetAllMembersRecursivly(type.BaseType));

Same result
Maybe???
The only workaround i found is to hardcode that type like that:
if (cj != null && requested == "massScale" && !path.Any())
{
    return ((v) => cj.massScale = v.Unbox<float>(), Il2CppType.Of<float>());
}

But that... MEH
More info:
I do some debugging and output all fields of type and its subtype:
base type: UnityEngine.ConfigurableJoint
fields:
set_targetPosition
set_xDrive
set_yDrive
set_zDrive
set_targetRotation
set_rotationDriveMode
set_slerpDrive
set_targetPosition_Injected
set_xDrive_Injected
set_yDrive_Injected
set_zDrive_Injected
set_targetRotation_Injected
set_slerpDrive_Injected
targetPosition
xDrive
yDrive
zDrive
targetRotation
rotationDriveMode
slerpDrive


base type: UnityEngine.Joint
fields:
get_connectedBody
set_connectedBody
set_axis
get_anchor
set_anchor
get_connectedAnchor
set_connectedAnchor
set_autoConfigureConnectedAnchor
set_enableCollision
set_enablePreprocessing
set_axis_Injected
get_anchor_Injected
set_anchor_Injected
get_connectedAnchor_Injected
set_connectedAnchor_Injected
connectedBody
axis
anchor
connectedAnchor
autoConfigureConnectedAnchor
enableCollision
enablePreprocessing

Flags: BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Declared for each subtype

Maybe a better solution is to pass the requested field through a Func<Joint, float> instead of a field name as string: jointObject => jointObject.massScale.

@OlivierJacot-Descombes no, field inside string required

I know it may sound weird but have you tried GetProperty instead of GetMember (and GetFiedl)?

@tschmit007 yes, that also wasn't working

You need to show the exact definition of the type you want to dig in using Reflection, but I can tell you the most typical mistakes leading to missing member information and the ways to overcome them.

To start it, use System.Type.GetMembers instead of System.Type.GetMember, traverse the array of all members, and try to find out what's missing. In nearly all cases it helps to resolve your issue.
More generally, you almost never need System.Type.GetMember. The problem is that the first argument is string, but how do you know that you provided a correct name and that you did not simply make a typo? Where does your requested come from? (Here is a hint for you: nameof). If you answer this question and are interested in knowing how to go around without System.Type.GetMember and strings, most likely I will be able to suggest the right technique for you.
Another typical mistake is the wrong BindingFlags value. First, you need to use my first advice to see what are the correct features of your member. An even clearer approach is this: start with the following value: BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static. That's it, nothing else.

Added:
I got another idea: I don't know how the reflected data is presented by the UnityExplorer. It looks flat, but what if some type members come from nesting types? I forgot about them. By the way, on the picture from `UnityExplorer, the problematic member is invisible.
Anyway, this is the code I suggest to investigate the problematic type:
First of all, I want to show all the library types used in the code I'll show:
using Type = System.Type;
using Console = System.Console;
using MemberInfo = System.Reflection.MemberInfo;
using PropertyInfo = System.Reflection.PropertyInfo;
using FieldInfo = System.Reflection.FieldInfo;
using BindingFlags = System.Reflection.BindingFlags;

Now, this is the investigation code sending the information we need to know to System.Console:
    public static class ReflectionSample {
    static readonly BindingFlags flags =
        BindingFlags.Static |
        BindingFlags.Instance |
        BindingFlags.Public |
        BindingFlags.NonPublic;
    public static void FindAll(Type type) {
        MemberInfo[] members = type.GetMembers(flags);
        foreach (var member in members) {
            string memberOrField = string.Empty;
            if (member is FieldInfo fieldInfo)
                memberOrField = $"{fieldInfo.FieldType.Name} field";
            else if (member is PropertyInfo property)
                memberOrField = $"{property.PropertyType.Name} property";
            else
                memberOrField = "(method)";
            Console.WriteLine(
                // + is not nice, just to format code for the answer:
                $"Declaring Type: {member.DeclaringType.Namespace}.{member.DeclaringType.Name}, " +
                $"Member Type: {member.MemberType}, " +
                $"Member Name: {member.Name}, " +
                $"{memberOrField}");
            Type[] nestedTypes = type.GetNestedTypes(flags);
            foreach (var nestedType in nestedTypes)
                // go recursive:
                FindAll(nestedType);
        } //loop
    } //FindAll
} //ReflectionSample

Could you try it and report the result? You could, say, redirect the output to some file and copy its content to the text of your question.

I already try ALL of that, check the question please before making an answer

Where is the declaration of the type you're reflecting in your question? And I doubt that you tried it all. Anyway, your question doesn't show those attempts. Look, if you need really working help, you need 1) try to follow the advice, 2) create short but comprehensive code to reproduce and provide it in your question. Not a fragment of your real code, but a comprehensive short code sample with a problem anyone can build and run. Mind you, your problem is not just easy to solve, but very easy to solve, in case you provide meaningful and comprehensive issue report.


You can see at "more info" all fields of type ConfigurableJoint and Joint (check "base type: " line), plus you can see at screenshot that its Joint field.
Its impossible to make short code that reproduces that, since its don't work only at certain game at specific cpp2il decompile. And yes, everything you say there i try already before even making a question, and almost every result of that attempts i wrote on question


BUT for you i will rewrite results:
Joint.massScale field EXISTS. I can get/set that field directly and everything works fine.
So type i was using is Joint. As you can see in More Info section there no field with that name for UnityEngine.Joint.
As i was saying i already try .GetMembers at What Fails and More Info section. I literraly output everything that was returned by that method, and there no that field. Same for second tip. And you can check i use same binding flags at What Fails section (i try almost every combination). So again, read question first!

More info? Sorry, that's not it. You need to create a code sample for the definition of the type you're trying to reflect, say, class A, and only then the code sample of reflection, apply this reflection code to this class A, and indicate the member present in class A and missing from the data obtained in reflection. It would be useful not to use just your real reflection code, but to create only the reflection code focused exclusively on the member of class A causing the issue. All the code should be self-contained without dependencies, so anyone could build and run it.

...I'm continuing my previous comment. If you do so, 1) chances are, you will resolve the problem yourself, because... you know, divide and conquer. 2) there are many people here who will be able to resolve the issue in no time, including myself. Please see the first sentence in my answer.

Are you even hear me? You can't run and build a mod without game decompile assemblies and game itself. And i'm also can't make pure il2cpp class with same signature as Joint, since there no point in it (the problem inside decompiled il2cpp unity assemblies for that unity version). Its not problem about reflection usage, thats a problem of cpp2il unity builtin assemblies, and i just asks for workarounds for that.

Yes, I hear you. That's why I say: you don't need to provide your real code, you need to develop a special simplified code without dependencies yet reproducing the issue, so anyone can run it. Now you try to hear me. But just the relevant fragment of the class you're reflecting on can help.

i will just repeat myself again: I have melonloader on il2cpp game and try to write mod for it., thats a problem of cpp2il unity builtin assemblies for that game, You can't run and build a mod without game decompile assemblies and game itself. Will you buy > install > load melonloader for that? Because spectial simplified code will require entire game atleast.

Do I have to repeat myself? We don't need it. You need to model the problem with a code specially developed to reveal the problem, not using your real code. But at least you could show a fragment of the class you're reflecting, the fragment of your real code to see what is that missing member. So far, you're doing your best to avoid helping me to help you.

Bro... its UnityEngine class... i can't shot its fragment... And there youre minimal reproducable code: Console.WriteLine(Il2CppType.Of<UnityEngine.Joint>().GetMembers(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static)). That output doesn't include massScale. Are you happy now?

Happy now? No, you did not hear me. That was not too bad in the first place. We need the relevant fragment of the type you're reflecting, the type with the member missing from Reflection. The actual definition of this type, that is, a fragment of its source code. Or you don't have it? If so, how do you know the missing member is there? Please clarify.

AND AGAIN: Its UnityEngine type, there NO SOURCE CODE for that. That exactly dll was GENERATED by cpp2il. That field INCLUDED in COM of UnityEngine.Physic module, and decompile of that property just re-invokes cpp method by pointer of pure c++ pointer to Joint type. READ. THE. QUESTION. AGAIN: Problem is that cpp2il DOESN'T include property massScale into type description on dll generation.

Thank you for the clarification. Please don't think it was obvious, but sorry that I did not see it before I asked you explicitly. Then I cannot add anything, but I could do the investigation using your hands. In particular, you could reflect only the fields (if you are absolutely certain that the missing member is a field) not with Linq, but in a loop, produce test text output, and add that text to the description of your question. Also, your Unity diagnostics is just an image, and the name of the field is not visible. Images don't work, only text.  And better use BindingFlags from my answer.

there NO fields in il2cpp types, since cpp2il makes getter/setter for each pure c++ field that will directly change value of it. Also there no reason to change to usual for loop, but yeah, i already try that before making a question. And yes, again, there already output of that in my question at "More Info" section. And i already try almost any sensable combination of binding flags, including youre (check the code in question!). And that NOT a unity diagnostics, its unity explorer, that uses UnhollowerLib to fetch fields (and it works, but i wont put is as dependency)

Wait a minute. I have another idea. I will add to my answer a bit soon enough. What you say suggests that you may need to reflect absolutely all members, including functions... and... Ok, I'll do something and will notify you.

Could you look at the new section Added in my answer and run the code against the type in question and show the output? — Thank you.

At my GetAllMembersRecursivly i already check all nested types + almost same code i already run and got More Info output (i cut Il2cppSystem.Object declarations). You sure you need almost same output from More Info section?

I can see only the fields in your output, and I inspected everything instead. Could it be something else, not a field?

actually i think thats all members (since there also get_ and set_ methods), but i don't sure. I will check code for that output later and maybe use your'e one
